# delete "&nbsp;" in php

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace, html-entities

With this url http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=fr&q=150euro=?dirhams, we can have a currency convert.

This is the result : `{lhs: "150 Euros",rhs: "1 691.50299 Moroccan dirhams",error: "",icc: true}`

I try to work with this result which looks like json.
So I use `json_decode` but it doesn't work.

So I thought it looks like serilize/unserialize so I use `unserialize` but it doesn't work.

Nervous, I used regexp and at the end I've got my value in dirhams with an `&nbsp;` because the value gets 4 numbers before the coma.

And this `&nbsp;` I can't delete it ! I try preg_replace, str_replace... no ways !

This is the function

I just want to get the "dirhams value", only the numbers, as a float

Anyone can help me ?

```
public function convertDirhams($prix, $monnaie_base = 'euro', $monnaie_convert = 'dirhams')
{
    $prix = urlencode($prix);
    $monnaie_base = urlencode($monnaie_base);
    $monnaie_convert = urlencode($monnaie_convert);
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=fr&q=$prix$monnaie_base=?$monnaie_convert";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    /*$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
    $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
    $var = $data['0'];*/

    $data = preg_replace('/ /','',$rawdata);
    $data = explode(':',$data);
    $data = preg_replace('/"/','',$data[2]);
    $data = preg_replace('/Moroccandirhams,error/isu','',$data);
    $prix_final = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$data);
    //echo $prix_final;


    return (float)trim($data);
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about json_decode? (Given that there's no `&nbsp;` referenced in this code, I doubt highly that's the issue here)

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Same as @BillyONeal, `json_decode()` should work. What error message/result do you have ?

Comment: Also the `&nsbp;` appears when you ècho`this in your browser, as the space between `1`and `691`is a **n**on **b**reaking **sp**ace. The `&nbsp;`isn't your problem.

Comment: @Billy: It's not valid json. The keys aren't quoted.

Comment: @MarkB: True, but I don't think that json_decode is that strict. I can't test ATM though...

Comment: @Billy : When I use json_decode, my var which stocks the result is empty. And the &nbsp is a big problem, because when I take this value and I give this to Zend_Currency the value is no numeric. And if I add (float) ... 1 600 = 1 <= and this is a very big problem ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was stuck with this issue when i used google currency converter. I tried many things and nothing worked for me. Finally i found this piece of code.

You can try with :

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.]/', '', $number);
```

or

```
$number = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $number );
```

Both works perfectly fine. `ereg_replace()` is depreciated function in php5.3.